# name of my macbook air changed automatically

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, mojave, logs

i noticed that the name of my macbook air in terminal changed automatically to "homepc"

This is the log of the console with the exact timeline it happened:

```
NetworkServiceProxy.framework/Versions/A/NetworkServiceProxy (0x7fffb250bdc0) and /usr/libexec/networkserviceproxy (0x10201e390). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Aug 15 00:57:00 Alexs-Air syslogd[47]: ASL Sender Statistics
Aug 15 00:57:06 Alexs-MacBook-Air findmydeviced[91598]: objc[91598]: Class LocalizedUnregisterErrorKey is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FindMyDevice.framework/Versions/A/FindMyDevice (0x7fffb11a13a8) and /usr/libexec/findmydeviced (0x105338d10). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Aug 15 00:57:08 Alexs-MacBook-Air com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Aug 15 00:57:14 homepc xpcproxy[91608]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 529: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Aug 15 01:04:08 homepc prl_naptd[90721]: Reloading configuration...
Aug 15 01:04:08 homepc prl_naptd[90721]: vnic0: DHCP/NAT for 10.211.55.1-10.211.55.254 netmask 255.255.255.0
Aug 15 01:04:08 homepc prl_naptd[90721]: vnic1: DHCP for 10.37.129.1-10.37.129.254 netmask 255.255.255.0
Aug 15 01:04:09 homepc timed[88]: settimeofday({0x5d546231,0x3a658}) == 0
Aug 15 01:04:10 homepc systemstats[59]: assertion failed: 18F132: systemstats + 214542 [0A10FDEF-5C7C-3D70-97F1-3A1D67836242]: 0x6d8f
Aug 15 01:04:10 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Aug 15 01:04:10 homepc com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.preferen
```

What just happened?
[image: ss of terminal]

EDIT:

The question which this is supposedly a duplicate of says this

```
It's perfectly normal for this to occur; when you login Terminal remotely bash does a reverse DNS lookup
```

I have never logged in remotely. I checked in system preference>sharing and all sharing is turned off including "remote login"

Comment: Hi, welcome to the AskDifferent help forum.
By looking at your terminal output, I can tell you that the name of your macbook air is Alexs-MacBook-Air and not homepc as you think. :-)
Open a new terminal session and type this command:

cd /

This will bring you to the root of your file system.
I wanted to add a screenshot but it's not possible in a comment.
Try what I suggested and let me know what the result was.

Comment: Hey @DaktaMoriamé, well that is not my terminal console but sys log console. I tried what you suggested and it still says "homepc" on my terminal. But i checked the name of my computer in system prefereces> sharing and it is "Alexs-MacBook-Air ". I wonder what "homepc" is and where  did it get that name. Thanks for your support

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your terminal plz?
I find this very odd...

Comment: screen shot added

Comment: And when you type this command in your terminal:
echo $HOSTNAME
What's the result? It should normally show you the correct hostname. :-)

Comment: it says "homepc.cowrks.com" cowrks is my office where i am right now. So i guess that kind of solves the mystery as to where it got the name "homepc" from. Can you tell me why would my hostname change to that?

Comment: Bash did a reverse DNS lookup. It will only be the same if the hostname is not specified on the network you're connecting from and there is no reply from the DHCP server, or the reverse lookup against the remote DNS server fails to resolve.
I would suggest this: flush the DNS cache by typing:

dscacheutil -flushcache (in a terminal session)
Reboot your machine... After reboot it should be back to 'normal'

Comment: You are very welcome!